# Python - Configuring multiple buttons at once in Tk

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have eighteen buttons that need to all change from one image to another upon the press of another button.  I could just call .configure on each and set it that way, however, I feel as though there is a much cleaner simpler way.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the buttons are all in a list, you can loop over them, like this:

```
self.buttons = [button1, button2, ..., button18]

def updateButtonImage(self):
    for button in self.buttons:
        button.configure(image=self.newImage)

updateButton = Button(root, text="Change button image", command=self.updateButton)
```

Is that what you had in mind?